# chromedriver in headless mode doesn't work correctly because of windows user policies

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The case - I can get access to my AUT only from my company's virtual machine, connecing to it by RDP.

I'm using jmeter's jsr223 samples to create the load by means of a chromedriver (interacting with it by org.openqa.selenium methods, sending the instructions by http requests to localhost).

If i don't add `chromedriver.addOptions("--headless")` so that chromedriver actually opens a GUI chrome window, everything works fine. However, with --headless options something goes wrong - I start the chromedriver, `get.url("http://AUT/login/page")`, fill username\password fields, logging in succesfully, clicking the  which opens a new window, switch to this window (I log every action, so I'm pretty sure, that until this moment everything works fine), but in this new window I'm trying to perform `element.sendKeys` (which works ok in 99.9% cases in GUI mode) but, get a timeout exception (actually using `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.xpath('//bla-bla/bla'))).sendKeys("zzzz");`) and always get a timeout exception. 
When I log the hole document's innerHTML, I can clearly see that //input i'm trying to access is present in the document.

Also tried to launch the --headless variant from my colleagues local machine (which also has access to AUT hosts) - everything works fine. However I'll have to generate the load from hosts, accessed by RDP, and if the headless mode won't work on it, I'll be fired&killed (:. So can anyone please tell me, which group policies in Win7 can affect the headless chromedriver work?

Also I had to add `ChromeOptions.setExpirementalOption("useAutomationExtension",false)` because without it, (even in non-headless mode) I get a warning box `"Can't load extension from .... Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator"` However, after clicking OK in this warning, the test continues without any problem.

It seems, that I'll have to require some special Windows group policy modifications from my companies SysAdmins && security service for the success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updating chrome to v66 and chromedriver to v2.38 in combination with setting the following options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--headless");
```

Solved the problem

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem to

Comment: I had met the similar issue. I can run my test case in my local chrome on Mac. But the test case always failed in Docker container based on selenium/standalone-chrome in headless mode. Finally, I have  fixed the issue by adding the option '--window-size=1920,1080' in headless mode. Maybe the window size will affect the chrome driver.

Comment: Make sure the argument `'--proxy-server=direct://'` is written without quotes around `direct://`. Otherwise, you could encounter Chrome's `ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck trying to get a JMeter test to work running a headless Selenium (standalone) chromedriver script on a Docker instance, from my corporate Win machine. Ran fine on my personal Linux machine, but on the corporate network kept on being blocked by the proxy (ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES network error).  The proxy 'direct' trick worked.  I know it's different issue to the OP's problem, but just documenting in case someone else finds this post. So the option that worked for me was just:

```
options.addArguments("--proxy-server=direct://")
```

Answer (score 0):

After making following changes to my code. It started working like a charm:

```
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--headless");
```